# Iterating through list in 'spiral'

Tags: python, image

I have an image that looks like this:

> [image]

I've converted it into a 2D list. What's the best way to iterate through this list in a 'spiral', starting at the top left and ending in the centre. The goal is to read in all non-black pixels.

Comment: Probably best to use numpy here. What have you tried?

Comment: Any tips on how to start with that?

Comment: If you already have the spiral mask, why not just use a cull according to the value in your case if it's white (255, 255, 255) then do... I would do this with shaders or at least some sort of multi-threading: [Shadertoy](https://imgur.com/nFRZhlo)

Comment: Note: with Gino Mempin's edit, the image is a bit confusing. An unintended consequence was, the white doesn't show up on StackOverflow's background as in imgur. So if we don't highlight the image, it may seem like the trail starts in the lower right. This threw me off when I posted an answer and went to double check things. I suppose a solution would be to re-upload the image but with a #c0c0c0 color instead of #ffff00.

Comment: @aschultz Sorry about that. I re-edited, wrapping the image in a blockquote to put a non-white background. You can also click on the image to display it on a dark background.

Comment: @GinoMempin no worries! It's something I wouldn't have seen if I'd made that edit. You can't expect to see every last detail. Your putting the image in a blockquote is a neat idea I'll remember in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code I have that progresses through spirals, starting in the upper left and going clockwise. It is naive (doesn't make use of that we *know* there are spirals) and simply prints out the coordinates, but I hope you can modify it to what you need.

I've checked several edge cases, because you need to make sure (0,1,2,3 mod 4) x (0,1,2,3 mod 4) all work. And wide spirals and squarish spirals need to be considered.

```
def do_stuff_with(my_array, x, y):
    print("Do stuff with", x, ",", y) #obviously, you will want to return or manipulate something. But this code is just about traversing the spiral.

def spiral(my_array, width, height):
    x_left = 0
    x_right = width
    y_top = 0
    y_bottom = height
    x_c = y_c = 0
    print("Bounding box {0},{1} -> {2},{3}".format(x_left, y_top, x_right, y_bottom))
    if x_left >= x_right or y_top >= y_bottom:
        print("Invalid spiral range.")
        return
    while x_left < x_right and y_top < y_bottom:
        #print("Going right")
        for i in range(x_left, x_right):
            do_stuff_with(my_array, i, y_top)
        #print("Going down")
        for i in range(y_top + 1, y_bottom):
            do_stuff_with(my_array, x_right - 1, i)
        if y_bottom - y_top > 1: # this just prevents us from revisiting a square in, say, a 5x7 spiral
            #print("Going left")
            for i in range(x_right - 2, x_left, -1):
                do_stuff_with(my_array, i, y_bottom - 1)
        if x_right - x_left > 1: # this just prevents us from revisiting a square in, say, a 7x5 spiral
            #print("Going up")
            for i in range(y_bottom - 1, y_top + 1, -1):
                do_stuff_with(my_array, x_left, i)
        # we need to fill in the square that links an outer spiral with an inner spiral.
        if x_right - x_left > 2 and y_bottom - y_top > 4:
            do_stuff_with(my_array, x_left + 1, y_top + 2)
        x_left += 2
        x_right -= 2
        y_top += 2
        y_bottom -= 2
        print("Top/bottom overlap", y_top >= y_bottom)
        print("Left/right overlap", x_left >= x_right)

def test_spirals(xi, yi, xf, yf):
    '''an exhaustive test to make sure different rectangles/spirals work'''
    for x in range(xi, xf):
        for y in range(yi, yf):
            print(x, y, "spiral test")
            my_array = []
            for z in range(0, y):
                my_array.append([0] * x)
            spiral(my_array, x, y)

# squarish tests: it seems like the main cases are (0/1/2/3 mod 4, 0/1/2/3 mod 4) so these 16 should knock everything out
test_spirals(4, 4, 8, 8)
# rectangular tests--yes, this overlaps the above case with 5x(6/7) but we want to try all possibilities mod 4 without having too much data to read.
#test_spirals(2, 6, 6, 10)
```

Let me know if you need or want clarifications.

ETA: here is some pseudocode for if you know you are reading in a spiral, but I think it is a big assumption. Also, this pseudocode is untested. But the idea is: go right til you hit a wall or black square, then down, then left, then up. Then repeat. Also, check for unnecessary trackbacks that may cause you to loop at the innermost line near the end.

```
def traverse_known_spiral(myary, width, length):
    do_stuff(0, 0)
    x_c = 0
    y_c = 0
    while True:
        x_c_i = x_c
        y_c_i = y_c
        while x_c < width - 1 and myary[x_c+1][y_c] == WHITE:
            do_stuff(x_c+1, y_c)
            x_c += 1
        while y_c < height - 1 and myary[x_c][y_c+1] == WHITE:
            do_stuff(x_c, y_c+1)
            y_c += 1
        if x_c_i == x_c and y_c_i == y_c: break # if we did not move right or down, then there is nothing more to do
        x_c_i = x_c
        y_c_i = y_c
        if y_c_i != y_c: # if we didn't go down, then we'd be going backwards here
            while x_c > 0 and myary[x_c-1][y_c] == WHITE:
                do_stuff(x_c-1, y_c)
                x_c -= 1
        if x_c_i != x_c: # if we didn't go right, then we'd be going backwards here
            while y_c > 0 and myary[x_c-1][y_c-1] == WHITE:
                do_stuff(x_c, y_c-1)
                y_c -= 1
        if x_c_i == x_c and y_c_i == y_c: break # if we did not move left or up, then there is nothing more to do
```

Comment: As I probably should have clarified in my question, the spiral is made up of many shades of gray with a black spiral between. I assume I can use `!= BLACK` instead of `==WHITE`? Also, is `WHITE/BLACk` just defined as `(255/0)`?

Comment: I originally assumed that WHITE=1 and BLACK=0 and you had a 2-color bitmap. But yeah, 1) in a 256-color bitmap WHITE could be 255, and 2) with the information that the spiral is various shades of grey, ==WHITE in my pseudocode should be replaced by !=BLACK.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out